How to add scrollbar for reactflow viewport and it should work for all sides
I have added scrollbar and it's working perfectly for right and bottom side.when new digram components is adding at right and bottom side scrollbar is increasing correctly,but when components are adding at top or left side scrollbar is not increasing also when I am using zoom in,zoom out,fit controls of reactflow,it's not working for left and top side what should I do
I have added scrollbar like this
useEffect(() => {
  const handleResize = () => {

    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.style.overflow='auto';
    };
  }

  handleResize();
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

  return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }
}, []);


ref is reference for my reactflow component
